# Total Derangement (Difficulty Level: Hard)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, fastest-algorithm

**The problem:** Write a function which, given a cycle length `n` and a number of cycles `m`, where 'm' is within `[2, n-2]`, generates `m` random cycles, each of length `n`, and all of which are [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of each other. Then `n=7`, for example, `m` could be `2, 3, 4, or 5`. All possible sets of `m` cycles of length `n` that fit the criteria should have equal probability of occurring.

**What is a cycle?** Imagine you're hopping around a list. Each element in the list is a number corresponding to another position on the list. Start out at the first element, and update your position to be whatever index is at that element:

```
CycleThrough(list)
{ 
    pos = 0;
    while(true) { pos = list[pos]; }
}
```

If you can visit every element in the list and get back to the start using this method, it's a cycle. If you can't, it's not. Here are a few examples of cycles:

```
(0)
(1, 0)
(1, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 1)
(1, 2, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 0, 2)
(2, 4, 1, 0, 3)
```

Take the last cycle. It goes `0 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 0`. What isn't a cycle? Take `(4, 0, 3, 2, 1)`- this isn't a cycle because it goes `0 -> 4 -> 1 -> 0`, and you won't hit `3` or `2`. Or take `(1, 1)` - it goes `0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 1...` and it never gets back to 0, so it's not a cycle.

**What does it mean for two cycles to be deranged?** Lets say you have two cycles, cycle `A` and cycle `B`. If `A[i]` never equals `B[i]`, they're derangements of each other. If you have more than two cycles, they're all derangements of each other if all pairs of cycles are derangements.

The fastest algorithm (in time complexity) wins.

Example outputs for n=5, m=3:

```
{{1, 4, 3, 0, 2}, {3, 0, 4, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 0}}
{{3, 0, 4, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 3, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 1, 0, 2}}
{{3, 0, 1, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 3, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 0, 2, 1}}
{{3, 4, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 4, 0, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 0}}
{{3, 4, 0, 1, 2}, {4, 0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 0}}
{{4, 2, 0, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 0}, {1, 4, 3, 0, 2}}
{{4, 3, 0, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 1, 0, 3}, {3, 2, 4, 1, 0}}
{{4, 0, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 0, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 3, 1, 0}}
{{3, 0, 1, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 0, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 4, 2, 0}}
{{3, 2, 0, 4, 1}, {4, 0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 3, 0, 2}}
```

Example outputs for `n = 4...12, m = n-2`

```
{{2, 3, 1, 0}, {3, 2, 0, 1}}
{{4, 0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 0}, {2, 3, 4, 0, 1}}
{{4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 0}, {2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3}, {3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 2}, {5, 3, 0, 4, 2, 1}}
{{6, 3, 5, 0, 1, 4, 2}, {1, 5, 4, 2, 6, 3, 0}, {5, 2, 3, 6, 0, 1, 4}, {4, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 3}, {3, 6, 1, 4, 2, 0, 5}}
{{7, 0, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {6, 2, 0, 7, 5, 1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 6, 2, 3}, {5, 3, 6, 4, 0, 7, 1, 2}, {4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 0, 5, 1}, {3, 7, 1, 5, 2, 4, 0, 6}}
{{2, 3, 6, 8, 0, 4, 1, 5, 7}, {8, 5, 0, 2, 1, 6, 7, 3, 4}, {3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 8, 6, 0}, {4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 0, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 8, 7, 4, 6, 3, 2, 0, 5}, {7, 0, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 6}, {5, 7, 1, 6, 3, 8, 0, 4, 2}}
{{1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 9, 8, 3, 0, 7}, {4, 2, 7, 1, 9, 3, 5, 0, 6, 8}, {9, 5, 0, 8, 3, 7, 1, 4, 2, 6}, {5, 7, 6, 0, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 3}, {7, 6, 8, 9, 5, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2}, {2, 8, 9, 7, 1, 6, 0, 5, 3, 4}, {8, 0, 3, 5, 6, 4, 9, 2, 7, 1}, {6, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5}}
{{3, 4, 1, 5, 8, 9, 0, 10, 6, 7, 2}, {1, 2, 6, 4, 10, 8, 5, 9, 7, 3, 0}, {10, 6, 3, 1, 9, 7, 8, 4, 0, 2, 5}, {8, 3, 0, 7, 2, 6, 10, 5, 9, 1, 4}, {9, 5, 7, 6, 0, 3, 2, 8, 4, 10, 1}, {2, 0, 9, 10, 7, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8}, {6, 7, 5, 8, 3, 4, 1, 2, 10, 0, 9}, {4, 8, 10, 9, 6, 0, 7, 1, 2, 5, 3}, {5, 10, 4, 0, 1, 2, 9, 6, 3, 8, 7}}
{{6, 11, 4, 5, 3, 1, 8, 2, 9, 7, 0, 10}, {1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 3, 7, 6, 2, 0}, {7, 9, 10, 1, 11, 3, 2, 8, 6, 0, 4, 5}, {4, 2, 5, 0, 6, 7, 9, 11, 1, 10, 8, 3}, {10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 0, 4, 1, 3, 11, 9, 2}, {9, 3, 6, 8, 7, 10, 1, 0, 5, 2, 11, 4}, {8, 0, 9, 11, 1, 4, 7, 10, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {3, 6, 0, 10, 2, 9, 11, 5, 4, 8, 1, 7}, {2, 5, 11, 7, 8, 6, 10, 9, 0, 4, 3, 1}, {11, 7, 1, 2, 0, 8, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 9}}
```

Comment: Please either clarify what the ambiguity is that remains or remove the hold on my question. I believe I have corrected everything you asked, and aside from that I don't believe it violates the rules in any way.

Comment: Can you give an example with `n=9, m=7`? (If you can then there's a further ambiguity, which is what the distribution of the random cycles should be: I presume it's selecting a random set of valid derangements such that each set is selected with equal probability assuming a perfect random number generator, but that's not entirely clear; however, the task being actually possible is a much bigger problem).

Comment: An answer for n=9, m=7 is {{5, 3, 4, 2, 0, 7, 8, 6, 1}, {2, 0, 8, 6, 5, 3, 1, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 0, 5}, {8, 6, 0, 4, 7, 1, 2, 5, 3}, {3, 7, 5, 1, 2, 0, 4, 8, 6}, {4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6, 0, 1, 2}, {6, 8, 3, 5, 1, 4, 7, 2, 0}}

Comment: I cleared up ambiguity and stated that all the different ways of doing it with m cycles of length n should have the same probability of occurring

Comment: If you'd like I could share all the code I've produced so far working on this problem.

Comment: "The fastest algorithm (in time complexity) wins." There's two parameters here, `m` and `n`, so it's not clear how to compare tradeoffs between these. If you mean for `m` to be linear in `n`, that would resolve it.

Comment: The worst case time complexity will always be when m=n-2 (since that's the maximum value m can take on for the challenge). Different algorithms will be compared for that case.

Comment: If n is an odd number than m can be n-1 but that isn't covered in the challenge

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52408/cyclic-mutual-derangements

Comment: Is it fine to use built-in combinatorial functions?

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), \$O((n - 1)!^{m - 1}nm)\$ expected time

This is a reference answer using a very straightforward and slow rejection sampling algorithm, for the sake of having at least one valid answer. It picks \$m\$ random cycles, checks whether they form a valid solution, and repeats from scratch until they do.

Since there exists at least one valid solution, there must exist at least \$(n - 1)!\$ valid solutions (by relabeling it), so the probability that \$m\$ random cycles happen to be a valid solution is at least \$\frac{(n - 1)!}{(n - 1)!^m}\$. So we expect at most \$(n - 1)^{m-1}\$ iterations of the loop, with each iteration taking \$O(nm)\$ time. (This is a pessimistic analysis that could be improved with a better lower bound on the number of solutions.)

```python
import random

def f(n, m):
    while True:
        cycles = []
        for i in range(m):
            order = list(range(1, n))
            random.shuffle(order)
            cycle = [None] * n
            for a, b in zip([0] + order, order + [0]):
                cycle[a] = b
            cycles.append(cycle)

        if all(len({cycle[j] for cycle in cycles}) == m for j in range(n)):
            return cycles
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNTsQwDIX3PYWXDhONQCM2SL0Cq9lVWWSmDs0oTaI0FRoQZy/5oUUF72y/5/fJ/h4HZ0/LokfvQoQgbe/GpulJgULLYWQvDaR6H7QhOIeZap/rer8amqCFTmwz5QJo0DZfeiNc7Wu50FNIDqOniFXyxMEytlNViuM0zEoZwmLaK0p0Tn51lgQ8gN2tM4XkcMkgH9pj9yjgUMP5D8MB0vAP3Xa5kyIdv/yPnI7Se7I9lo41m0IrkMagIYuf9cRNFIxKmjiq/4tB28JYVrffP6UP7FECxTmspsUHbSMqfOZwYmz5Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, ~O(n!):

```py
import collections, copy, random
def cycles(n):
   q, q1 = collections.deque([([], [0 for _ in range(n)], 0, {}, {*range(n)}, collections.defaultdict(set))]), collections.deque()
   while q:
     result, a, s, d, ac, cache = q.popleft()
     if not ac:
        yield a, cache
        continue
     for i, x in enumerate(a):
       if (s or i) and (i not in d and s not in cache[i]):
          l, _cache = copy.deepcopy(a), copy.deepcopy(cache)
          _d = copy.deepcopy(d)
          l[i] = s
          _d[i] = s
          _cache[i].add(s)
          q.append((result, l, i, _d, ac - {s}, _cache))   

def main(n, m):
   cycle, result, cache, seen = [*cycles(n)], [], {}, []
   while 1:
     if len(result) == m and result not in seen: 
        yield result
        result, cache, seen = [], {}, seen + [result]
        continue
     c, _cache = random.choice(cycle)
     if all(not cache.get(j, set())&_cache[j] for j in _cache):
        result.append(c)
        cache = {j:cache.get(j, set())|_cache[j] for j in _cache}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLjtswDLznK3gqpK3W2G17WBjIlxhGIEj0RoEsybaCbpDm21NKfqVpYsCARXPIIWcUTnHv3c@P0F@vpg2@j6C8taii8W4QdAgnAb102rcbjQ2ok7I4MMfLDQB0Arp32N5iCo3dEVnFqlpA9QaN72EHxqUin0hACr8JOF/ofZljF3FXopFHG7VRkQ0YOa@5eNCDJwq/98YidJkOQI8DAQVIAcRe04cipFR7JJZdEXyw2MQRCWAacD5SzoSm52TQ6gTPoCWsvIvGHadAmskI@EpjoTu22MuITPKlDBVmA6QsDrQ7YCY3onSdz8N8zF0qU69QeqyA3cw5CUDjYkgf1ELcRXIevwHv9H8offvfUjfKGP6BPIjNzAqpNRtuK3SFDAGdZmzeNhGmdezyuuEVzsNlnoBzAmyyc1ppHHMC2nHWbCSxCJazSTRER0yql8VnyUX16JeqXgV/LxcJLbqJCYftFtq84TEwrzmVLeFO5DFlCT5hMvXOx@9QjVn1E2OoG@XGS1OovTcKWZ5ntZ20liVuObn4xMgOqQc5k3@bVn@os88Oif@0zPKO7CyEWuWZu58P5YPaf57WvlyzqdeL@kvAx9gw9MZF5vArsqwhSW1ef3DOr38B)

Comment: This doesn’t work. `next(main(5, 3))` hangs forever about 1 in 6 times. (Convenient that your TIO link only tests 5 times!) I think that’s due to a bug, but even with the bug fixed, a strategy like this can’t possibly work. For example, with n = 6, m = 4, there is no way to extend [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0], [2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 4], [3, 4, 1, 5, 0, 2] with a fourth cycle.

Comment: No. There do exist solutions for n = 6, m = 4—an example is listed in the challenge—and the challenge requires you to find them all with equal probability. You just can’t use your row-by-row strategy, since you might start with those dead-end rows. This is marked “difficulty level: hard” for a reason.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I was under the impression that only one block of `m` cycles had to be produced for the solution to be valid (based on "Example outputs"), hence the use of a generator + `next`. Anyway, I will look deeper into this later.

Comment: I’m skeptical that this strategy or anything similar can satisfy the challenge’s requirement that “All possible sets of *m* cycles of length *n* that fit the criteria should have equal probability of occurring”; do you have any reason to believe that it does? Also, your \$O(mn)\$ claim is not even remotely plausible, given that you have at least three nested loops with lots of restart conditions, and you generate less than half an output per second at *n* = 6, *m* = 4.

Comment: Now this doesn’t have any randomness at all. The challenge asks for a *single* random block of *m* cycles, where all valid outputs occur with equal probability. And I don’t know what you’re measuring with \$O(n^3)\$, but it’s definitely wrong.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Added a bit of explanation to a randomized version of my previous solution, although even Python's `random` module is pseudo-random, so who knows. I suppose it would be valid to simply produce all possible `m` cycles, and then choose one randomly, but I think that goes against the spirit of the question.

Comment: You still aren’t outputting a *single* random block of *m* cycles. There is no reason for `main` to be a generator; the challenge just asks you to output one random block of *m* cycles. (If the challenge asked for a uniformly random die roll, a solution would be `def main(): return random.randrange(1, 7)`—nothing else.) Putting that aside, your generator can still get stuck on the same dead-end rows I described earlier, and when it doesn’t get stuck, it still doesn’t satisfy the equal probability requirement. And it takes *at least* \$O(n!)\$ time to generate your cycle pool.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Thanks for the clarification on `O(n!)`, will take a look at the possibility of dead-end rows later.